# Where is the default max locked memory value coming from?

Tags: apc, ulimit

So on one system, I have values that are pretty wide open:

```
$ ulimit -a | grep mem
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 40000
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Another system has much more limiting values, but I can't for the life of me find out where the 32MB upper limit (it is 32MB despite the mislabling) is being set:

```
# ulimit -a | grep mem
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

The second system is a RHEL 5.5 box. I am looking to increase this limit for at least one user- I need a bigger APC mmap memory allocation, but I can't go above 30 MB without running into the above limit, and I would rather not hack the provided apache init script. Where should I be trying to override the system default value so I can map a bigger segment of memory? Doing it in limits.conf for the apache user doesn't do a whole lot; probably because the init script doesn't do anything through PAM.

Answer (score 0):

If the user granularity setting you tried isn't working, you should make sure that's you've correctly matched which user is hitting the limit.

You should also be able to add a line like this to limits.conf:

```
* hard memlock 40000
```

That'll change the default setting for all users.

From the limits.conf manpage:

```
The syntax of the lines is as follows:

<domain> <type> <item> <value>

The fields listed above should be filled as follows:

<domain>

[snip]
·   the wildcard *, for default entry.
```